# no + or * register when entering vim from ranger

Tags: register, os-clipboard

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with i3wm. Vim and vim-gtk3 packages are installed.

If I'm in a regular terminal and I start editing a file in vim. I can yank text to the `+` register as expected. However, if I am browsing the filesystem with `ranger`, and I use ranger to open a file in vim, I cannot use the `+` register. If I try typing `"+yy` to yank a line, I get an error bell when I press `+`. The same goes for the `*` register.

As far as I can tell, everything else is the same about vim. I can't figure out why just the clipboard registers won't function in this specific case.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Check output of `:version` when you start Vim both ways. Do both of them include `+clipboard` among the features? You might have two separate Vim binaries and you're getting one or the other depending on how you start it. Please [edit] the question to report on your additional findings.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing here, as I don't have a Ubuntu to verify (anymore).

I assume that you have two different Vims installed on your machine. This is not unusual (try `ls -l /bin/vim.*`).

Open Vim from the command line and then execute the command `:version` in it. This will print version information and a list of features. The feature list will contain the string `+clipboard`, so clipboard is supported.

Now start Vim from inside `ranger` and also run `:version`. This time you will find `-clipboard` in the feature list. This means no clipboard support.

If my assumptions are true, you need to configure `ranger` to use the right version of Vim. This [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367452/how-to-change-the-default-text-editor-in-ranger) has answers (also none is accepted).

Answer (score 0):

You are using default vim (default with many *nix installations), which does not allow system clipboard manipulation. Install either gVim or Neovim (I suggest the latter); these applications come with default clipboard management ability. Then, you can copy and paste from system clipboard, etc.

You can check this by opening your terminal and typing `vim --version`. If it states `- clipboard`, you have the default installation that you will need to remove and reinstall the others mentioned above.